# Prism.StoreApps VS template10

Tags: win-universal-app, prism, template10

Is there a detailed comparative study of features on Prism.StoreApps Vs Template10?  Got from stackoverflow that Template10 uses PRISM underneath.

But How do we evaluate an end-to-end Universal App with Prism.StoreApps and Template10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks JerryNixon for the answer. It is great to have an answer from the author of Template 10.

As on today, Template 10 targets UWP. And when we look at developing Cross-Platform Apps( IOS/Android) using XAMARIN, there is a need for us to look at PRISM for XAMARIN or MvvmCross .

We would love to have a SINGLE solution for both UWP and XAMARIN (Cross-Platform).

Would there be any updates in Template 10 to include XAMARIN to cater to cross-platform devices?  Obviously, Windows10 tablet-specific controls like Hamburger ,etc would need to have a replacement of rendering for phone devices and a single pattern of Template10 for developing UWP and Cross-Platform apps would help. But could be worked about.

If you have this in the roadmap of Template10, kindly do let know. 
We could even wait for such features on Template10.

Answer (score 7):

**Template10** is a boilerplate template for UWP application which provides a great starting point for building the application. Additionally template10 also provide some frequently used controls, behaviors, converters, services and basic support for MVVM pattern.

Note you can start with Template10 and integrate various features from Prism in Template10 project.

Complete documentation for Template10 you can find here: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki

Whereas **Prism** is an advanced framework applying best practices and approaches to allow developers build loosely coupled, highly maintainable, and testable application. Prism allows developers to build a very well structured and maintainable code for the application, although there is a learning curve involved to understand all features initially but once known devs can build a pretty robust applications. That's the reason Prism is very popular in Enterprise apps world.

MSDN: documentation associated to prism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx this cover most of the concepts.

Important thing to note both Template10 and Prism is open source project available on GitHub so you can anytime dive into the code and try out samples.

Template10: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10

PrismLibrary: https://github.com/PrismLibrary

Answer (score 6):

I am one of the authors of Template 10. So, take my answer with a grain of salt, please. But, I am being very honest here.

The history of Template 10 starts with Prism. When Prism was not upgraded for UWP, Template 10 was born, and from Prism it brought with it a lot of code and many techniques. There is nothing Prism can accomplish that Template 10 cannot. And, Template 10 has a very large community for support and far more documentation. The Prism documentation you find on MSDN is for Windows 8, not Windows 10. That being said, there is nothing wrong with Prism. But Prism is just a tiny subset of Template 10's capabilities.

Comment: I'm glad a read this, I wanted to start larning about prism but I got so angry because the documentation was only for windows 8.  I will take a look at Template 10 :D